# Filtering PHP to search Key and Value

Tags: php, rest

i have a problem here, im trying to search some value from the key but it keep showing all array (example : i want to search satuan = FLS, but it keep showing all data array, not showing the data that i search)

this is the code

```
//connection
include 'koneksi.php';

//Parameter
$param=$_GET['param'];
$v=$_GET['v'];

//SQL
if($param=='')
{
    $sql="select * from obat";
}else if($param<>'')
{
    $sql="select * from obat where $param like '%$v%'";
}
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$res['obat']=array();
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $ft['kode']=$data['kode'];
    $ft['obat']=$data['obat'];
    $ft['produsen']=$data['produsen'];
    $ft['satuan']=$data['satuan'];
    $ft['harga']=$data['harga'];
    array_push($res["obat"],$ft);
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `else if` when the condition is the opposite of the first condition. Just use `else`.

Comment: im getting same result, it keep showing all array

Comment: That wasn't an answer, it was just general advice. I can't see any reason why you're getting everything.

Comment: Are you sure the parameters are in `$_GET` rather than `$_POST`?

Comment: Add `var_dump($_GET);` to see if you're getting the parameters you expect.

Comment: This is dangerous code, as it opens you to SQL injection, look into using prepare for your query, also I would do (needs sanitizing!!)
```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM obat";
if ( ! empty($param)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE $param LIKE '%$v%';";
}
```

Comment: Ignore MySQL for now, focus only the creating the `$sql` variable, dumping that out so you can see that. Once you get that working, then start dealing with the database.

Comment: im still getting same result, is my code wrong? im sorry because im new using REST and PHP @BarrieDawson

Comment: `REST` doesn't usually put parameters in the query parameters, they're in the URL itself. E.g. `script.php/satuan/FLS` rather than `script.php?param=satuan&v=FLS`. You can't get that from `$_GET` unless the server rewrites it.

Comment: ohh u're right @Barmar so i need to set the key to param & v as the key and satuan & FLS to value

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there, I don't know what you mean by key and value. If you're using a URL like that, you get the part after `script.php` from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. It will contain `/satuan/FLS` you can use `explode()` to get the parts.